# How to have python shell '>>>' symbol pop up in a program

Tags: python, shell, interactive

I am creating a simple interactive python tutorial. But I have encountered a problem that I need the shell to combine my commands with their tests. The problem with inputs are that they will not produce the response that the python shell would. With very simple programs, it would be easy for me to produce the answer, if their syntax was correct. However, if it did involve complex code or the user wanted to stray from the path and experiment or change parts, it would produce the wrong response. Thus, it would be useful if there was a command for the shell to take over.

```
print('Here is a challenge for you: Get python to print a sentence of your choice')
```

Then from the shell, it would give the user an oppurtunity to try this out, and for python to take over.

```
#Insert code to make shell command symbol appear
>>> #Represents the place for commands on the python shell
```

After this operation, it would go back to the programs control.

Comment: And what happens when they type in `import os; os.system('rm -rf /')`?

Comment: You are pretty much just looking for something like `input(">>> ")`. However, the previous comment raises a very important concern that hopefully you are going to handle in your code.

Comment: PS: **Do NOT try to run the Daniel's command** :P

Comment: PPS: *If you run Daniel's command he nor StackOverflow are responsible for the fubar you committed on your computer*

Comment: Need `sudo` access for that.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Wouldn't that popup a permission error or something?

Comment: Well you can always `print('>>> ')` in the hopes of fooling your users...

Comment: The whole point of that `rm` question was not to in turn question the validity of whether "sudo" will be needed, etc.....the point is to bring up the realization that this type of solution opens the doors to very malicious code.

Comment: @Coldspeed So it's not possible?

Comment: Glad to see you did not run that `rm -rf` command @matt-333

Comment: @idjaw There is a possibility that the last comment was from the OP's mobile :P

Comment: I'm curious and I can't find anything on google. What are the full implications of runnning it and what exactly happens along with fouling up my system beyond recognition?

Comment: You'll have to reinstall your OS.

Comment: @DanielRoseman It didn't work for me.

Comment: One option could be to [create a course](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm-edu/quickstart/getting_started_educators.html) using the free PyCharm Edu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it, using [`os.system`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system). Try this:

```
import os
os.system('python')
print('Done.')
```

Output:

```
$ python test.py
Python 2.7.10 (default, Feb  6 2017, 23:53:20) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.34)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> ^D
Done.
```

`os.system` will block in this case, waiting for the process to return with whatever status (0 usually).

You can also use [`subprocess.Popen`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) (example with 3.5.0):

```
import subprocess
process = subprocess.Popen(['python3.5'], shell=True)
process.communicate()

print('Done')
```

Output:

```
$ python3.5 test.py
Python 3.5.0 (v3.5.0:374f501f4567, Sep 12 2015, 11:00:19) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> ^D
Done.
```

---

As everyone mentioned in the comments, it is very unsafe to give the user unbridled reign over your system. ***Use at your own risk.***

Comment: What does os.system do? And why does it produce a tab that suddenly dissapears?

Comment: I was wondering why you'd revoked your  acceptance. `os.system` will fork a new subshell and execute the command you pass. By the way, you'll probably have to ask the user to exit from the interpreter to return control to the program. You can also look at Popen. I've linked you to the documentation for both.

Comment: Also, what OS and python version are you on? I've used 2.7 to demo.

Comment: I'm using 3.5.1. The output that you were given on 2.7 is not produced when ran on 3.5.1

Comment: Okay, just tried it with 3.5 and it works fine. What's the issue? Are you on windows?

Comment: @matt-333 I've edited my answer with an example for popen. Check it out.

Comment: Oh I understand the problem. I wasn't running it through the shell, it doesn't work on a program.

Comment: @matt-333 Popen too?

Comment: I suppose in a way they both do produce '>>>' . If I run it in the shell it produces a python shell on cmd. Can you explain more about os and why it is dangerous?

Comment: Both are dangerous. :) The reason being, you are allowing the user to execute commands on the shell that you cannot control. As the parent program, you have simply forked a shell and washed your hands off what happens after that. The user could type in anything they want on the interactive shell, and python would execute it. You would need to set strict permissions to ensure that they cannot do things like `import os`; `os.unlink('.')`, thereby _deleting your entire directory_, or even worse.

Comment: No worries... as long as you understand the consequences of what you're doing!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147635/discussion-between-matt-333-and-coldspeed).